# cakephp 2, editing form creates a new record instead of updating it

Tags: cakephp

I'm using the console cake bake to generate forms automatically from the database.
I have a problem though, one of my controllers instead of updating a record after editing it, is creating a new record into the database.

Comment: pass the table row `id` before saving/updating the form like `$this->modelName->id`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have used the console to bake your Views, your Edit forms should have this line:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id');
```

If it is not present, you should add it. This ensures that the id of the Object you are saving is present in the data sent to the Controller and then to the Model so it does not create a new record in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Another source of possible problems is that the form data is not in the request. Your updating function probably looks something like this:

```
function update($id=null) {

    //if the data has come back from the form...
    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        //Your saving code goes here.

    } 

    //else, the form is being requested initially, and the id is coming through
    //as a get parameter.
    else {

    $this->request->data = $this->Model->findById($id);

    }

}
```

I've gotten into trouble in the past by forgetting this line:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Model->findById($id);
```

In the second case of the conditional. If you forget that, then regardless of whether you echo the hidden id field to the form or not, it will not contain the id in its "value" attribute and when the request comes back to the action function your saving code won't know what to make of it, and instead it will create a new record.